# Is it necessary to use else branch in async expressions?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I want to write the following code:

```
let someAsync () = async {
    if 1 > 2 then return true // Error "this expression is expected to have type unit ..."
    // I want to place much code here    
    return false
}
```

F# for some reason thinks that I need to write it like that:

```
let someAsync () = async {
    if 1 > 2 then return true
    else
        // Much code here (indented!)
        return false
}
```

In latter case no error message is produced. But in my view both pieces of code are equivalent. Is there any chance I could avoid unnecessary nesting and indentation?

**UPD.** What I am asking is possible indeed! Please take a look at [example](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-i-return.aspx/), see section *Real world example*

I will quote the code:

```
let validateName(arg:string) = imperative {
    if (arg = null) then return false  // <- HERE IT IS
    let idx = arg.IndexOf(" ")
    if (idx = -1) then return false    // <- HERE IT IS

    // ......
    return true 
}
```

So, it is possible, the only question is if it is possible to implement somehow in `async`, via an extension to module or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important difference between the `async` computation builder and my `imperative` builder.

In `async`, you cannot create a useful computation that does not return a value. This means that `Async<'T>` represents a computation that will eventually produce a value of type `'T`. In this case, the `async.Zero` method has to return `unit` and has a signature:

```
async.Zero : unit -> Async<unit>
```

For `imperiatve` builder, the type `Imperative<'T>` represents a computation that may or may not return a value. If you look at the type declaration, it looks as follows:

```
type Imperative<'T> = unit -> option<'T>
```

This means that the `Zero` operation (which is used when you write `if` without `else`) can be computation of any type. So, `imperative.Zero` method returns a computation of any type:

```
imperative.Zero : unit -> Imperative<'T>
```

This is a fundamental difference which also explains why you can create `if` without `else` branch (because the `Zero` method can create computation of any type). This is not possible for `async`, because `Zero` can only create `unit`-returning values.

So the two computations have different structures. In particular, "imperative" computations have monoidal structure and async workflows do not. In more details, you can [find the explanation in our F# Computation Zoo paper](http://tomasp.net/academic/papers/computation-zoo/)

Comment: That's what I supposed. But I had a hope there might be some shortcut that would help. Nonetheless, thanks to your `imperative` example I created my own workflow which combines it with `async`. Might be not very smooth, but it works fine.

Comment: @Rustam - I'd be curious about that - did you define your own type of computations? I'd think that it is not possible to define the second kind of `Zero` method for standard asyncs...

Comment: Yes, I used your example and I wrapped `async` into it also, as a secondary kind of computation. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/GusRustam/10081383 I am not sure if that code is completely safe, but currently it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think that situation is described here: [Conditional Expressions: if... then...else (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233231.aspx)

> (...) if the type of the `then` branch is any type other than `unit`,
>   there must be an `else` branch with the same return type.

Your first code does not have `else` branch, which caused an error.

Comment: Interesting... I was sure I saw how such constructs `if xxx then return false` were used in custom computation expressions and I just wanted to check if it could work in `async` also. I will double check...

Comment: See section Real-world example

Comment: @Rustam - This is one of those things that you can do, but is probably a bad idea unless you really know what you are doing

Comment: @JohnPalmer Well, I find computation expression a very powerful tool, but a bit contrived indeed. Despite that I would rather try to get used to them

Comment: Well, this quote only refers to ordinary `if` .. `then` .. `else` expressions not inside the computation expression block. Inside computation expressions, the situation is more subtle and it depends on how `Zero` and `Combine` members are defined. For more details see: http://tomasp.net/academic/papers/computation-zoo/